# Get only max values from table for each ID record

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I am having table like this, where id is repeating several times.

[image]

I need to get only max L1 value for each ID, so correct result from the query would be:

| L1 | ID | VALUE_VARCHAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 224754148 | xDSL 1 - node_id atribut |
| 2 | 224754147 | adef_node_id_test_99 |
| 4 | 224754121 | node_id_bijelnia_dvorovi |
| 4 | 244378018 | 1 |

Table:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, ID, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (1, 224754121, 'node_id_bijelnia_dvorovi');

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, ID, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (1, 224754147, 'adef_node_id_test_99');

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, ID, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (1, 224754148, 'xDSL 1 - node_id atribut');

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, ID, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (1, 244378018, '1');

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, ID, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (2, 224754121, 'node_id_bijelnia_dvorovi');

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, ID, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (2, 224754147, 'adef_node_id_test_99');

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, ID, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (2, 244378018, '1');

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, ID, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (3, 224754121, 'node_id_bijelnia_dvorovi');

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, ID, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (3, 244378018, '1');

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, ID, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (4, 224754121, 'node_id_bijelnia_dvorovi');

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, ID, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (4, 244378018, '1');
```

Comment: If you only need to take the maximum value of L1 and don't need other field data, you only need a simple GROUP BY ID and then MAX(L1) to get it

Comment: I need values from all columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using max(l1)over window function:

```
select distinct max(l1)over (partition by idn),idn,value_varchar
from my_table
order by max(l1)over (partition by idn)
```

Sample:

```
create table my_table (l1 number, idn number, value_varchar varchar2(100));

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, IDn, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (1, 224754121, 'node_id_bijelnia_dvorovi');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, IDn, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (1, 224754147, 'adef_node_id_test_99');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, IDn, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (1, 224754148, 'xDSL 1 - node_id atribut');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, IDn, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (1, 244378018, '1'); 
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, IDn, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (2, 224754121, 'node_id_bijelnia_dvorovi');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, IDn, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (2, 224754147, 'adef_node_id_test_99');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, IDn, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (2, 244378018, '1');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, IDn, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (3, 224754121, 'node_id_bijelnia_dvorovi');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, IDn, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (3, 244378018, '1');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, IDn, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (4, 224754121, 'node_id_bijelnia_dvorovi'); 
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(L1, IDn, VALUE_VARCHAR) VALUES (4, 244378018, '1');
```

Result:

```
1   224754148   xDSL 1 - node_id atribut
2   224754147   adef_node_id_test_99
4   224754121   node_id_bijelnia_dvorovi
4   244378018   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Analytic functions, such as `row_number`, help:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select l1, id, value_varchar,
  3            row_number() over (partition by id order by l1 desc) rn
  4     from my_table
  5    )
  6  select l1, id, value_varchar
  7  from temp
  8  where rn = 1
  9  order by id;

        L1         ID VALUE_VARCHAR
---------- ---------- ------------------------------
         4  224754121 node_id_bijelnia_dvorovi
         2  224754147 adef_node_id_test_99
         1  224754148 xDSL 1 - node_id atribut
         4  244378018 1

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH sorted_data AS
(
  select l1, id, value_varchar, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY  l1 DESC) as r from my_table
)
SELECT * FROM sorted_data WHERE r = 1;

4   224754121   node_id_bijelnia_dvorovi    1
2   224754147   adef_node_id_test_99    1
1   224754148   xDSL 1 - node_id atribut    1
4   244378018   1   1
```